# Trying to change url of image(FXML) in controller class (javafx)

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, fxml

How to change the url thats in the  tag in the FXML file with my controller.

The Image is nested in pane > childeren > Imageview > image 
see picture

[image]

**What I want**

I want to loop through the imagevies to check the coordinates and with the right coordinate change the url.

This is my loop

```java
for (int i=0; i < 54; i++) {
    if (objectsPane.getChildren().get(i).getLayoutX() == village.getX() && objectsPane.getChildren().get(i).getLayoutY() == village.getY()) {
        objectsPane.getChildren().get(i). // Setting the url
    }

}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can't change the URL of an existing image: you need to set a new image for the `ImageView`: `settlement1.setImage(new Image(...))`.

Comment: I have 54 ImageViews I don't want to use there id's.

Comment: It's probably better to create them in the controller, instead of in FXML. Then you can just put them in a `List`, or whatever data structure is most convenient.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean yet

Comment: Creating all those image views in FXML is very verbose and repetitive, because FXML doesn't have loops. Create them in the controller instead, in Java code, because you can use loops and data structures like `List`s to easily manage them.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to do a type casting, because `objectsPane.getChildren().get(i)` gives you the `ImageView` as of the type `Node`. Then you can create a new image with the new url. As James commented, it is not possible to just change the url. Finally you replace the old image with the new one. Your code could then look something similar like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
    if (objectsPane.getChildren().get(i).getLayoutX() == village.getX() && objectsPane.getChildren().get(i).getLayoutY() == village.getY()) {

        // Type cast from Node to ImageView:
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) objectsPane.getChildren().get(i);

        // Create new image with new url:
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/img/gameobjects/new-image.png"));

        // Replace the old with the new image:
        imageView.setImage(image);

        // Or alternatively as a one-liner:
        //((ImageView) objectsPane.getChildren().get(i)).setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/img/gameobjects/new-image.png")));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I did this I placed a village like I wanted but when I did this again at the same ImageView to overwrite it with a different image it didn't work.
The village doesn't change.

Comment: It should be possible to change the image over and over again in the same way.

Comment: Your right. I didn't realise that I changed the layout whereby it could't find the imageview to change it again.